# Index to column

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to convert my Index to a column. But I get the Error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reset_Seriennummer'` It should be simple but it doesn't work.

My Index is ot called Index but it is written the same way:

My df:

```
Seriennummer    0
701085.0    "(array([1.52558046e+03, 2.55900548e+02, 5.96901108e-01]), array([[ 9.41414894e+03, -2.07982124e+03, -2.30130078e+00],
       [-2.07982124e+03,  1.44373786e+03,  9.59282709e-01],
       [-2.30130078e+00,  9.59282709e-01,  7.75807643e-04]]))"
701086.0    "(array([1.19304206e+03, 2.71174688e+02, 6.59205468e-01]), array([[ 5.21906135e+03, -2.23855187e+03, -2.11896425e+00],
       [-2.23855187e+03,  2.61036500e+03,  1.67396324e+00],
       [-2.11896425e+00,  1.67396324e+00,  1.22581746e-03]]))"
```

What I tried so far:

```
df['Seriennummer'] = df.Seriennummer
```

or

```
df.reset_Seriennummer(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Do you want `df = df.reset_index()` ?

Comment: ```df['Seriennummer'] = df.index``` should convert your index into column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
df.reset_index(level='Seriennummer')
```